# How to sort an array of objects by type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I want to sort data based on a specific logic.

The rules for ordering are:

1. Type : Actual.
2. Type: Projected.

This is my code:

```js
const myData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "businessEntityId": "BE001",
    "financials": {
      "Npbt": 2323,
      "Interest": 123213,
      "Depreciation": 213123,
      "Ebit": 1312321,
      "EbitDa": 123123,
      "Leasing": 123213
    },
    "type": "Actual",
    "startDate": "2018-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2018-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "model": "Commercial",
    "duration": 12,
    "quality": "Unqualified"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "businessEntityId": "BE002",
    "financials": {
      "Npbt": 2323,
      "Interest": 123213,
      "Depreciation": 213123,
      "Ebit": 1312321,
      "EbitDa": 123123,
      "Leasing": 123213
    },
    "type": "Projected",
    "startDate": "2017-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2017-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "model": "Commercial",
    "duration": 12,
    "quality": "Projection"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "businessEntityId": "BE002",
    "financials": {
      "Npbt": 2323,
      "Interest": 123213,
      "Depreciation": 213123,
      "Ebit": 1312321,
      "EbitDa": 123123,
      "Leasing": 123213
    },
    "type": "Actual",
    "startDate": "2017-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "endDate": "2017-06-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "model": "Commercial",
    "duration": 12,
    "quality": "Audited"
  }

]

var order = {
  model: {
    Commercial: 2,
    Agribusiness: 1
  },
  type: {
    Historical: 3,
    Actual: 2,
    Projected: 1,
    Proforma: 0
  },
  Actual: {
    Unqualified: 3,
    Qualified: 2,
    Audited: 1
  },
  Projected: {
    Projection: 3,
    Qualified: 2,
    Audited: 1
  },
  BOTTOM: Infinity
};

let result = myData.sort(
  (a, b) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-expressions
    return order.model[a.model] - order.model[b.model] || order.type[a.type] - order.type[b.type]
  }
);

console.log(result.map((obj) => obj.id))
```

So when I run the sort , the result is currently(check console for react app / result):

```
id 1, id 2, id 3.
```

I was expecting: `1,3,2`?
How can I sort on Type respecting these rules and have `type='Projected'` at the bottom?

Comment: good pickup mate

Comment: Can you please delete this question if you got this fixed or fix your file and edit the question?

Comment: It is not fixed yet

Comment: Question: *I was expecting: 1,3,2?* Why? 2nd object has `type: "Projected"`. So it should be first. Should it not?

Comment: @bierhier I have updated your question and made your code as a snippet. Please rephrase/ update any details  accordingly.

Comment: @Rajesh thanks it is working now.

Comment: It seems the HOF `Array.sort` would come in handy here